# Does a Blessed character need to be in at least the rank of a power to be able to cast it?

Tags: savage-worlds, magic, deadlands-reloaded

In the Savage Worlds Deadlands Reloaded setting, does a Blessed character (the modified version of Arcane Background Miracles that is casting without needing powerpoints) need to be at least of the same rank as a power to be able to cast it? Or: can a novice blessed character cast a seasoned power?

The rules state, that the Blessed character casts novice powers at -2, seasoned at -4 and so forth, but I believe does not explicitly state if all higher spells are available using this malus right after creation or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a Blessed you have access to all powers at all levels from character creation, with appropriate modifiers based on their level (-2 for Novice, -4 Seasoned etc). This is explained in the section on Blessed where it states 'you can petition your lord for any power available to the Blessed'.

See [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20907&highlight=blessed) for official clarification on the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is dead... so much for "official clarification" being preserved... anyone have another source anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Pg.83 of the Deadlands Players Guide says "Instead, You can petition your lord for any power available to the Blessed" Name the power and tell the Marshall its Rank. Your blessed makes a short prayer and you make a Faith roll. The roll is modified by the Rank of the power and  the any Modifiers your Marshall decides to add based on the reasoning behind the request .(No using Smite on the kid chewing gum during your Sunday sermon Padre.) So you should be allowed to ask for anything its just harder to ask for the big stuff.

Comment: Yes, but for nitpicking readers it is not defined what "any power available" is. One could interpret available as you need the proper level. Nonetheless, the accepted answer refers to an official ruling.